# Ghidra Python - cancel decompilation task

Tags: decompilation, python, ghidra

The way to decompile a function in Ghidra Python is:

```
    decomp = DecompInterface()
    decomp.openProgram(currentProgram)

    decompile = decomp.decompileFunction(func, 1000, monitor)
```

However, in some cases, probably due to an error or corner case situations, the decompilation takes much more than expected.

Any ideas on how is it possible to cancel a decompilation task, using any kind of timeout, in Ghidra Python? I know that it's possible in the  GUI. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already passing `1000` to a `decompileFunction` so according to the [documentation](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/app/decompiler/DecompInterface.html#decompileFunction(ghidra.program.model.listing.Function,int,ghidra.util.task.TaskMonitor)) an exception should be thrown if it takes more time than that. Though, the timeout is in seconds and you set it to pretty high value - probably assuming it's in `ms`. Change to `1` and check if it will be cancelled with an exception if the time has passed.

Alternatively, you use the `monitor` object that you are passing also to the `decompileFunction` method. It contains `cancel()` function that can cancel the action it has been passed to. You can read more about this object [here](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/util/task/TaskMonitor.html).